# XML to JSON conversion - issue in order of XML elements

Tags: json, xml

regular method returns JSON data in a different order of elements that are present in original XML data.

here is main code I have used

```
       JSONObject obj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);

            jsonString = obj.toString();
```

Here is the xml I have used

```
<root>
<items>
    <itemId>111</itemId>
    <quantity>3000</quantity>
</items>
<items>
    <itemId>333</itemId>
    <quantity>4000</quantity>
</items>
<Proptery1>test data</Proptery1>
<Proptery2>8799882</Proptery2>
<Proptery3>sampleURL</Proptery3>
<Proptery4>1710366</Proptery4>
```

any help to get same order in Json format would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not guarantee order - the specification explicitly states :

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

You may have to rethink what you are attempting.